# Paginação Assíncrona com laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Fiz uma paginação simples com o `laravel` usando o retorno do `->paginate()`,
porém, como vocês sabem, não é uma ação assíncrona, o que deixa a paginação ruim.

Achei alguns exemplos, mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Alguém tem dicas?

Comment: Você está querendo implementar uma paginação com `AJAX`, no `Laravel`? tem algum código ? Tem algum `HTML` e o `Model` relacionado os campos desse retorno ?

Comment: Do que você está falando? O que você está querendo fazer? Está tentando utilizar o Paginator` do Laravel junto com Ajax? Faço isso quase sempre e tem dado muito certo.

Comment: Isso mesmo wallace, tenho uma lista de itens do objeto já paginados pelo laravel, porem não estou conseguindo aplicar o ajax nela, vc tem algum exemplo?

Comment: @DouglasCarvalho o exemplo te ajudou, esclareceu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `$.post` do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) e o `paginate()` do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) tem uma forma fácil de trabalhar com `ajax`:

Exemplo:

*Tabela*

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela `parque` possui dois campos o `id` e o `description`

---

*Model* `Parque`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parque extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('description');
    protected $table = 'parque';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

---

*Routes*

```
Route::get('pagina', ['as' => 'pagina.get', 'uses'=>'PaginasController@index']);
Route::post('pagina', ['as' => 'pagina.post', 'uses'=>'PaginasController@post']);
```

*Controller* `PaginasController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Parque;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PaginasController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('parques');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        $data = ['data' => Parque::orderBy('description')->paginate(5)];
        return view('table', $data);
    }
}
```

---

*Pagina principal* (arquivo `parques.blade.php`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table"></div>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    function getTable(url)
    {
        if (url == '') url = "{{route('pagina.post')}}";
        $.post(url, null, function(data)
        {
            $('#table').html(data);
            linkAjax();
        },'html');
    }
    function linkAjax()
    {
        $items = $('#table table').find('[href]');
        $.each($items, function(index, element){
            var href = $(element).attr('href');
            $(element).attr('href', 'javascript:getTable("' + href + '")');
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getTable('');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*Trecho da tabela a ser carrega via* `ajax` (arquivo `table.blade.php`):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 20%">Id</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($data as $v)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$v->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->description}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="center" align="center">
            {{ $data->links() }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<sub>**Observação:** isso é um exemplo que deverá ser adaptado a seu projeto, devido a falta de informação, não pude refletir a um exemplo real, mas, funcional.</sub>